# How can I combine a string and a string size in a function in C++?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

I literally just started learning C++ yesterday, I have a basic knowledge of Java and am just trying the basics. I'm trying to make a very basic program to understand this language's syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string bacon = "How many characters are in the following? ";
    string chedder = "icecream";
    string cheSize = chedder.size();
    string snow = bacon + " " + "\"" + chedder + "\"" + "The number is : " + cheSize;

    cout << snow;
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I noticed cout cant combine multiple strings, for example

```
cout << snow + chedder;
```

doesn't work.

What is the reasoning for this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: `string cheSize = chedder.size();` size returns int not string.

Comment: What about [reading the famous manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) first before using stuff?

Comment: You cannot learn C++ by doing random stuff and asking stackoverflow why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
chedder.size()
```

has integer type `std::string::size_type`. There is no conversion constructor in the class `std::string` that can implicitly convert an integer to an object of the type `std::string`.

So this statement

```
string cheSize = chedder.size();
```

is wrong.

By this reason there is no overloaded `operator +` for an object of the type `std::string` and an integer. Instead you should use standard function `std::to_string` to convert an integer to a string and apply the `operator +`.

So instead use the following code

```
string bacon = "How many characters are in the following? ";
string chedder = "icecream";
string::size_type cheSize = chedder.size();
string snow = bacon + " " + "\"" + chedder + "\"" + "The number is : " + to_string( cheSize );

cout << snow << endl;
```

And this statement

```
cout << snow + chedder;
```

is correct provided that the both variables have the type std::string or one of them has the type std::string and other has a type of a character array or a pointer to char.

Answer (score 1):

`size()` returns an integer type (`std::string::size_type` to be specific), not `string`. And unlike some other languages, C++ won't automatically convert an integer to `string` when you assign to a string variable.

If you're using C++11 or newer, you can use the `to_string()` method to convert it.

```
string cheSize = chedder.size().to_string();
```

Comment: [`std::string::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) returns `std::string::size_type` to be precise!

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted:

```
cout << snow << " " << chedder;
```

Also note that, `chedder.size();` returns you an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an integer value to a string object.

```
std::string cheSize = chedder.size(); // error
```

If you want then you can use `std::to_string`:

```
std::string cheSize = std::to_string(chedder.size());
```